# Ember.js 2 How to filter an existing model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, filter, ember-data

I'm currently learning Ember 2, and I'm trying to figure out the best approach to stacking model filters in Ember.js (2.4.2 with CLI workflow) and Ember Data.

Specifically, I am wondering if there is a good way to apply filters to an existing route's filtered model, without overriding any filtering that the route (or other component) itself may be doing.

My problem is this:

#### I have log entries (model "entry") which are sorted by date and associated with a user by user ID (model "user").

Model as defined in `/app/routes/index.js`:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  // ...

  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      users: this.store.findAll("user")
      entries: this.store.findAll("entry")
    });
  },

  // ...
});
```

Model is overwritten in `/app/routes/user.js`:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  // ...

  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      users: this.store.findAll("user")
      entries: this.store.filter("entry", function(entry) {
        // ...
        return entry.get("userId") === userId;
      })
    });
  },

  // ...
});
```

When viewed, `localhost:4200/` lists all entries, and `localhost:4200/user/alice` lists all entries owned by the user named "alice". Likewise, `localhost:4200/user/bob` lists all entries by user "bob".

#### I also have a filtering component that allows entries to be filtered by date.

Specifically, entries on or after a "from" date, and/or entries on or before a "to" date. These date filters need to be able to applied to both the index and user routes.

The problem comes in with the user route. I can do the following in `/app/components/log-filter.js` to filter by date (assume `this.entries` is the "entry" model passed as a template attribute from the current route):

```
// ...

var filtered = this.entries.store.filter("entry", function(entry) {
  var logDate = entry.get("logDate");
  return logDate >= filterDateFrom && logDate <= filterDateTo;
});

this.set("entries", filtered);
```

This code properly filters by "date from" and "date to", but it overrides the user name filtering when run in the user route.

The quick and dirty route would be to replicate the user name filtering in the date filter callback, but this is not DRY and it will quickly become unwieldy as more routes are added (category, location, etc.), since date filters need to be universal.

#### My question

This is a front-end-only app using local storage as its data store, so I can't use a backend to automatically filter out entries outside of ember.

1. Is there any way to filter against an existing model, rather than always starting with the global `*.store.filter("modelName", callback)` collection?
2. Is this even a good approach or is there a better, more "Ember" way of handling multiple arbitrary filters?

Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: Your backend should do the filtering for you. And to avoid overwriting your previous items you could use filteredEntries: Ember.computed.map('entries, entr => { }) map returns new array instead of changing original

Comment: Any idea how to do this for a front-end-only app with local storage as the data store?

Comment: I'd write an utils/filters.js file, where i'd store filtering methods and import these to your route, controllers, components. E.g "import {filterByDate} from 'app/utils/filters: and in route you would write something like that >  entries: filterByDate(store.peekAll('entries'))

Comment: Yeah I started trying something like that (with a service instead of generic utils) in one of my attempts, and that's starting to seem like the best approach. Thanks, I'll post an answer with what I end up getting to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter should definitely be done by your adapter. If a user enters `user` route directly, you won't have any `entry` records in store. You hack only works if a user enters via `index` route.

Also I think `userId` is not defined. I guess it's a dynamic segment of your `user` route?

```
// /app/routes/user.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      user: this.store.findRecord("user", params.userId)
      entries: this.store.query("entry", {
        filter: params.userId
      })
    });
  }
});
```

You could easily filter a [DS.RecordArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RecordArray.html) by [Ember.computed](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html) `filterBy()` or `filter()` methods or sort it with `sort()`.

```
// /app/component/user-view.js
Ember.Component.extend({
  filterDateFrom: new Date(),
  filterDateTo: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)),
  filteredEntries: Ember.computed.filter('entries', function(entry) {
    var logDate = entry.get("logDate");
    return logDate >= this.get('filterDateFrom') && logDate <= this.get('filterDateTo');
  })
});

// /app/templates/user.hbs
{{user-view entries=model.entries}}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry if that wasn't clear in the question, `userId` is generated in the `// ...` code that isn't directly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I used something like this to filter existing data

```
this.get('store').peekAll('role').filter( (role) => {
  return role.get('name') == 'Alan';
});
```

You can use `this.get('store').filter('modelName')` to query live records from the server.